# How to download files programatically from Google Storage via python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently trying to download some files from `Google Storage` using the [Python API](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/). Obviously this can be done by using [gsutil's cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp), and indeed I could do it.

`sudo gsutil cp gs://???/stats/installs/*.csv .`

However, all examples of `Google Python API` I've found don't cover this subject, I'm even considering if this functionality is covered by the API.

Comment: gsutil is written in Python; you can almost certainly look inside to see what it does. Although I actually think it's a wrapper around boto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *is* covered by [Python Example  |  Cloud Storage Documentation  |  Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-python-samples) (the 1st in Google on "google storage python wrapper"):

> To download an object: [`storage/api/crud_object.py` (View on GitHub)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/crud_object.py)
>
> ```
> def get_object(bucket, filename, out_file):
>     service = create_service()
>
>     # Use get_media instead of get to get the actual contents of the object.
>     # http://g.co/dv/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/python/latest/storage_v1.objects.html#get_media
>     req = service.objects().get_media(bucket=bucket, object=filename)
>
>     downloader = http.MediaIoBaseDownload(out_file, req)
>
>     done = False
>     while done is False:
>         status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
>         print("Download {}%.".format(int(status.progress() * 100)))
>
>     return out_file
> ```

Comment: By the way I was lookign at [this site](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=stats_export&rd=1#export) and they show a different approach using a `json` but the example doesn't work, 'cause `oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` and `apiclient.discovery import build` can't be found, maybe this approach isn't suported anymore? I want to avoid using `gcloud init`

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto that link seems to be about downloading some reports rather than user files.

Comment: Indeed I want to download those reports

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, looks like oauth2client changed how it does this: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/92e4ad332992b91d4674335f3d83a7181e38967d/CHANGELOG.md#special-note-about-serviceaccountcredentials